# Writing parameterized tests for JUnit, why are two of my parameters "null" when I run my tests?

Tags: unit-testing, parameters, junit, nullpointerexception, encryption

I'm doing an internship for a webapp security company, and one of my tasks is to write unit tests for files. The file I'm working on right now simply returns a password-based encryption cipher. The way I want to test the file is by making encryption and decryption ciphers that are based off the same password. Then, I want to encrypt and then decrypt a string, and compare it to the original string. The test passes if the two strings are equal.

To that end, I made a parameterized JUnit test class with 4 fields: one for the name of my test, one for the data I'm running through the encryption/decryption processes, one for the encryption cipher, and one for the decryption cipher. I initialize my ciphers in my setUp method before passing them to my `@Parameters` method.

However, I keep running into a `NullPointerException` when I run my tests. With the help of the Debug view in Eclipse, I've determined that for some reason, while all the parameters are set correctly in the `data()` method, when it comes time to run my actual `testMethod()` method, my `_name` and `_data` fields are correct, but my `_encryptCipher` and `_decryptCipher` fields are `null` instead. Why is this?

```java
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class TestClass {
    String _name;
    byte[] _data;
    Cipher _encryptCipher;
    Cipher _decryptCipher;

    public TestClass(String _name, byte[] _data, Cipher _encryptCipher, Cipher _decryptCipher) {
        this._name = _name;
        this._data = _data;
        this._encryptCipher = _encryptCipher;
        this._decryptCipher = _decryptCipher;
    }

    static CryptoManager cm;
    static Cipher SIMPLEPASS_ENCRYPT_CIPHER;
    static Cipher SIMPLEPASS_DECRYPT_CIPHER;

    private static final byte[] TEST_SALT = "!th1s_i.s_an 3x4mp+le &s4lt     4_t%35t1ng".getBytes();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {
        cm = CryptoManager.getInstance();
        cm.initPsc();

        SIMPLEPASS_ENCRYPT_CIPHER = CipherUtils.getPBECipher("abc123".toCharArray(), TEST_SALT, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
        SIMPLEPASS_DECRYPT_CIPHER = CipherUtils.getPBECipher("abc123".toCharArray(), TEST_SALT, Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);
    }

    @Parameters(name = "{index}: {0}")
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
           {"Test 1", "545671260887".getBytes(), SIMPLEPASS_ENCRYPT_CIPHER, SIMPLEPASS_DECRYPT_CIPHER}
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(_name, _data,     _decryptCipher.doFinal(_encryptCipher.doFinal(_data)));
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() throws Exception {
        cm.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `data()` is called before `setUp()`. Therefore `SIMPLEPASS_ENCRYPT_CIPHER` and `SIMPLEPASS_DECRYPT_CIPHER` are null.

You can create the Ciphers directly:

```
private static final Cipher SIMPLEPASS_ENCRYPT_CIPHER = CipherUtils.getPBECipher("abc123".toCharArray(), TEST_SALT, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
```

or withing the `data()` method:

```
@Parameters(name = "{index}: {0}")
public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
  SIMPLEPASS_ENCRYPT_CIPHER = CipherUtils.getPBECipher("abc123".toCharArray(), TEST_SALT, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
  SIMPLEPASS_DECRYPT_CIPHER = CipherUtils.getPBECipher("abc123".toCharArray(), TEST_SALT, Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);

  return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
    {"Test 1", "545671260887".getBytes(), SIMPLEPASS_ENCRYPT_CIPHER, SIMPLEPASS_DECRYPT_CIPHER}
  });
}
```